# linux tee is not responding

Tags: python, linux, tee

I made a Python script that communicates with a web server using an infinite loop.
I want to log every communication data to a file and also monitor them from a terminal at the same time. so, I used a tee command like this.

```
python client.py | tee logfile
```

however, I got nothing from terminal or logfile. The Python script is working fine. What is happening here?

Comment: Buffering behaves differently for pipes and terminals. You may need to do an explicit `sys.stdout.flush()` from your script whenever you logged a line.

Comment: For other ways to trigger unbuffered output see http://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/1328439

Answer (score 262, accepted):

From `man python`:

```
   -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to  be  totally  unbuffered.   On  systems
          where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.  Note
          that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines()  and  file-
          object  iterators  ("for  line  in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by
          this option.  To work around this, you will want to use  "sys.stdin.read‐
          line()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
```

So what you can do is:

```
/usr/bin/python -u client.py >> logfile 2>&1
```

Or using `tee`:

```
python -u client.py | tee logfile
```

Comment: An alternative would be to use `script`, which also disables buffering and additionally makes control sequences (`C-a`, cursor keys etc) work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39269661/15690.

Comment: excellent! it worked also in Python 3 on my Raspberry Pi 3 equipped with Raspbian Jessie:

python3 -u client.py | tee logfile

Comment: A note: python, like various other commands will use line buffered if stdin and stdout are consoles, but full buffered if the results are redirected to a file or a pipe. `tee` is seen like a pipe (which it is) and not the hybrid: it write to console. Note: the behaviour could be also controlled inside a python program.

Comment: Another note: `python -u client.py | tee >> logfile` would not work. The `>>` would introduce another case of buffered writing to a file. That's what `tee -a` solves.

Comment: One can also put -u into the shebang line and it works: #!/usr/bin/python3 -u

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making it fully unbuffered you can make it linebuffered as it is normally with `sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)` (after `import sys` of course).

This was added in 3.7, docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure