# Are tee and script essentially equivalent?

Tags: shell, monitoring, tee

In the context where I want to capture the *stdout* of a process in a file but still want to have this output displayed in the terminal I can choose between `script` and `tee`.  In this context, are these tools essentially equivalent or is there a – possibly subtle – reason to prefer one over the other?

---

The programs `script` and `tee` are designed for different purposes:

- `script` -- make typescript of terminal session
- `tee` -- pipe fitting

Important differences between `script` and `tee` are:

- `script` transmits the exit status of the process it supervises, while `tee`, being a filter, does not even know about it.
- `script` captures *stdin*, *stdout*, *stderr* of the process it supervises while `tee` only catches the stream it filters.

None of these differences are relevant in the given context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `script` to be useful for making control sequences work when piping to `tee`:

```
script -q -c 'python -c "import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()"' /dev/null \
| tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

With only the following, `Ctrl-A` would be displayed as `^A` etc:

```
python -c "import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()" | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

This is a minimal example.  I am using `tee` here to capture the output from a pytest test run, but sometimes there might be a debugger in there, and cursor keys etc should work then.

Via https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/1920.

Answer (score 5):

They have a very different purpose and the usage is quite different as well.

- Script is to record what you are doing in a shell session. Handy to show a professor what you did, to show co-workers how to do something, etc...
- Tee is just an application to write to both your screen and a file. Very handy when installing something or running a command that generates a lot of output and wanting to see the output realtime while still saving it to disk.

A notable difference between the two is that you can use script to create an interactive shell to log everything (e.g. `script commands.log zsh`) including colors and such. Tee won't register as a tty so with that regard it's pretty different.